# R Language indirection

Tags: r, nse

I'm a long-term developer but somewhat new to the R language. I'm trying to write some clean and maintainable code. I know how to do this in multiple languages but not R.

I've got an R function that performs the same action for different fields.

```
# working code but not DRY
summarize_dataset_v2 <- function ( data, dataset ) {
    switch ( dataset,
             hp = {
                 data %>%
                     group_by ( cyl ) %>%
                     summarize ( hp  = mean ( hp ),
                                 num = n ( ) ) ->
                     summarized_composite
             },
             wt = {
                 data %>%
                     group_by ( cyl ) %>%
                     summarize ( wt  = mean ( wt ),
                                 num = n ( ) ) ->
                     summarized_composite
             },
             stop ( "BAD THINGS" ) )

    return ( summarized_composite )
```

The actual code has 6-8 variants with more logic. It works but by being non-DRY it is a bug ready to happen.

Conceptually what I want looks something like this:

```
    switch ( dataset,
             hp = { field_name = "hp" },
             wt = { field_name = "wt" },
             stop ( "BAD THINGS" ) )

    data %>%
        group_by ( cyl ) %>%
        summarize ( *field_name = mean( *field_name ),
            num = n( )
        ) ->
        summarized_composite

    return( summarized_composite )
}
```

The `*field_name` construct is just there to illustrate that I'd like to parameterize that common code. Maybe currying that `summarize` statement would work. I'm using the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) stuff but I'm open to using another package to accomplish this.

Edit #1:
Thanks for the answers (https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993861/stefan, https://stackoverflow.com/users/12256545/user12256545)

I've applied both answers to my example code and understand (I think) how they work. The one from stefan matches my experience in other languages. The one from user12256545 comes from a different POV and shifts focus to the caller, giving it more power. I haven't done a lot of formula-based code so this is a chance to explore that facet.

I'm going to apply both approaches to my actual problem to see how they feel. I'll respond with the results in a few days.

Thank you both.

Edit #2:
When I applied these two approaches to my actual code I found that the one by stefan matched my mental model of how this would work. I accepted that as an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: You might find the ["Programming with dplyr"](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette useful (including the section on indirection). For a deeper dive, see the [rlang](https://rlang.r-lib.org/) tidy evaluation and metaprogramming vignettes, or the metaprogramming chapters of [*Advanced R*](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach to get rid of the duplicated code may look like so. First, `switch` is not necessary. Instead you could make use of the `.data` pronoun to pass column names as strings. Additionally I make use of some `glue` syntax and the walrus operator `:=` to name the "mean" column according to the column name passed as an argument:

```r
library(dplyr)

summarize_dataset_v2 <- function(data, dataset) {
  if (!dataset %in% c("hp", "wt")) stop("BAD THINGS")

  data %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarize(
      "{dataset}" := mean(.data[[dataset]]),
      num = n()
    )
}

summarize_dataset_v2(mtcars, "hp")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>     cyl    hp   num
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4  82.6    11
#> 2     6 122.      7
#> 3     8 209.     14

summarize_dataset_v2(mtcars, "wt")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>     cyl    wt   num
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4  2.29    11
#> 2     6  3.12     7
#> 3     8  4.00    14

summarize_dataset_v2(mtcars, "disp")
#> Error in summarize_dataset_v2(mtcars, "disp"): BAD THINGS
```

Answer (score 3):

Using formula syntax with aggregate could be an elegant solution in this case:

```
summarize_dataset <- function(form,data) {
  aggregate(
    form,data,
    FUN=\(x) { setNames(cbind(mean(x),NROW(x)),c("mean","N")) }
  )
}
# simple example:
summarize_dataset(formula(hp~cyl),mtcars)

#>  cyl   hp.mean      hp.N
#> 1   4  82.63636  11.00000
#> 2   6 122.28571   7.00000
#> 3   8 209.21429  14.00000

# more complex selection, group by two factors and three dependent vars:
summarize_dataset(formula(cbind(hp,mpg,disp)~cyl+am),mtcars)

#>   cyl am   hp.mean      hp.N mpg.mean    mpg.N disp.mean   disp.N
#> 1   4  0  84.66667   3.00000 22.90000  3.00000  135.8667   3.0000
#> 2   6  0 115.25000   4.00000 19.12500  4.00000  204.5500   4.0000
#> 3   8  0 194.16667  12.00000 15.05000 12.00000  357.6167  12.0000
#> 4   4  1  81.87500   8.00000 28.07500  8.00000   93.6125   8.0000
#> 5   6  1 131.66667   3.00000 20.56667  3.00000  155.0000   3.0000
#> 6   8  1 299.50000   2.00000 15.40000  2.00000  326.0000   2.0000

# all columns
summarize_dataset(formula(.~ cyl),mtcars)

# iris example
summarize_dataset(formula(Sepal.Length~Species),iris)
```